# Prove A' ∪ B′ = (A ∩ B)'

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Prove $A' ∪ B′ = (A ∩ B)'$
Let, $M=A' ∪ B′  $ and $ N=(A ∩ B)'$
Let $x$ be an arbitrary element of M then
$x\in M\Rightarrow x\in A'∪B'\Rightarrow x\in A'$ or $x\in B'\Rightarrow x\not\in A$ or $x\not\in B\Rightarrow x\not\in(A∪B)\Rightarrow x\in(A∪B)'$????
I think I'm doing something wrong, can you help me?

Comment: $x∉A$ or $x∉B$ ⇒ $x∉(A \cap B)$

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA Thanks!

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA so $x\in A'\not\Rightarrow x\not\in A$? and $x\in A\not\Rightarrow x\not\in A'$?

Comment: NO; $x \in A'$ means $x$ belongs to the *complement* of $A$. Bu the complement of $A$ is **defined** as the set of all elements that do **not** belong to $A$. Thus : $x \in A' \Leftrightarrow x \notin A$.

Comment: ok, definitely better

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Narrowly on your argument. It is fine as far as $x\notin A$ **or** $x\notin B$. But that does not imply that it is in **neither**, it implies that it is not in **both**. So yes, you did to do something wrong - almost at the end of your argument.

Comment: if $A,B\in R$ and $A\not=B$  
$x\in A' \Rightarrow x\in B\setminus\left \{A\cap B  \right \} $ and
$x\in B' \Rightarrow x\in A\setminus\left \{B\cap A  \right \}$
is it correct?

Comment: @vmahth1 What is $R$? The set $B\setminus (A\cap B)$ is a subset of $B$. So why should the fact that $x$ is **not in** $A$ imply that it **is in** $B$?

Comment: $x\in A' \Rightarrow B\setminus\left \{A\cap B  \right \}\in x $ , 
$x\in A'\not\Rightarrow x\in B\setminus\left \{A\cap B  \right \}$?

Comment: $A$ and $B$ are unrelated sets. Suppose we are looking at subsets of $X=\{1,2,3,4,5\}$ and $A=\{3,4,5\}$, whilst $B=\{1,3\}$. Then $A'=\{1,2\}$, $A\cap B=\{3\}$, so $B\setminus(A\cap B)=\{1\}$. Then $1$ belongs to both $A'$ and $B\setminus(A\cap B)$, but $2$ belongs to $A'$ and **does not** belong to $B\setminus(A\cap B)$.

Comment: so $B\setminus(A\cap B)\in A'$ and $A' \not\in B\setminus(A\cap B)$

Comment: You need to use $\subset$ not $\in$!

Comment: ok Thanks @almagest for help

Comment: But enough of this! You need to learn the definitions of complement, setminus etc carefully and work out some examples **carefully** on your own. Try Venn diagrams. They can be most helpful!

Comment: My problem was that he was currently I am using literature and was given a simple example and suddenly given more difficult tasks and it was difficult to do it on the way